# Añadir imagen destacada en Wordpress con PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

no consigo encontrar el error por el cual set_post_thubmaill no funciona. Mi codigo es este:

```
    $fotoid = media_sideload_image( $imagesres."/".$row->foto1, $restaurantid, '' );
    $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment($fotoid, $row->foto1, $restaurantid);
    $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $row->foto1 );
    wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );
    set_post_thumbnail($restaurantid, $attach_id);
```

Donde $imageres es la URL donde están almacenadas las imágenes y $row->foto1 es el nombre de la foto con la extensión. La imágen se sube correctamente a los medios, pero no se pone como destacada en el post.

Gracias!

Comment: Para errores específicos de un producto, lo más recomendado es siempre preguntar en sitios de soporte de dicho producto, en este caso, algún sitio de soporte de WordPress. Nos estás pidiendo que te digamos por qué no funciona el código que has puesto, pero no indicas ningún fallo, qué parámetros tienen los métodos que utilizas, qué devuelven, qué lógica hay... es decir, nos pides ayuda con cosas internas de wordpress, y das 0 información de tu problema ("No se pone como destacada" da 0 información, sinceramente). Es posible que alguien pueda ayudarte aquí... pero allí seguro que podrán muchos!

Comment: Este sitio es más específico para preguntas de Wordpress: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ (aunque en inglés)

Comment: ¿`$imagesres` o `$imageres`?

Comment: Para asignar una imagen tanto destacada como en galeria lo que debes asignar es el id de la misma, no la url, es decir, primero debes subir la imagen a wordpress, obtener el ID y luego asignar ese ID.